# Resistor calulation for two LED

Tags: power-supply, led

I want to connect two IR LED to the 3.3v output on the PI in series.  I need to reduce the 3.3v to 3.0v.  What kind and measure should my resistor be?

I swear this is not a word problem from school....

Emitted Color : Infrared IR 940nm Viewing 
Angle: 135 degrees 
DC Forward Voltage (VF): 1.4V 
DC Forward Current (IF): 700mA 
Maximum Pulse Voltage: 1.6V

Comment: 3V3 from a gpio or from the 3V3 rail?  A link to the IR LEDs would be useful.  What are you trying to do?  Illuminate a scene?  If so the IR LEDs would use more power than the Pi could probably supply.

Comment: Thank you for the foresight, but I really only need to know the resistor.  It doesnot matter which 3.3v output I am using, only that the LEDs need 3v power and not 3.3  :)

Comment: Emitted Color : Infrared IR 940nm 
      Viewing Angle: 135 degrees 
      DC Forward Voltage (VF): 1.4V
      DC Forward Current (IF): 700mA
      Maximum Pulse Voltage: 1.6V

Comment: A gpio may be able to supply 20mA.  The 3V3 rail on a B may be able to supply 50mA.  Both far short of the 700mA needed per LED.  A B+ may supply a lot more on the 3V3 rail.  I'm not sure if anyone has tried.  You might get a sustained 500mA from the 3V3 rail on a B+, or you might blow it up.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  What if I use the 5v rail?  What should be the current and then what would I need for a resistor if it is even possible?

Comment: A link to the IR LEDs would be useful.

Comment: The link is to an ebay auction, I provided the specs above

Comment: If we knew the precise model of the LEDs it might be possible to comment.  Selected features are not enough.

Comment: Please refer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ for more insight on the electrical behaviour. There is no such thing as to safely operate such a LED directly at GPIO pins.

Answer (score 1):

Germanium diodes have voltage dropout of about 0.3V, so you can use it in series with wanted IR diode. Or you can use 1 Ohm/! Watt resistor for this task.

Comment: Great. So if my two LED are connected in series and use 3v and 700mA then this 1 Ohm resistor will help when connected to a 3.3v power supply on the PI.....

Comment: Actually it looks like two LED in series will be 3,2v but what does that do to the current? and if in series, will the pi be able to power these leds?

Answer (score -1):

I use two similar IR LEDs to send short RC code bursts without resistor without problems. If that#s your application then you should be fine. You may run into burned out LEDs, though, if the pin stays high for too long due to some issue.